# curl: (6) Could not resolve host: localhost

Tags: dns, docker

Hi i have problems resolving localhost in a docker container

```
[devcontainer]$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost
[devcontainer]$ curl localhost
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: localhost
```

also node has the same problem

```
[devcontainer]$ /home/plutus/.vscode-server/bin/e713fe9b05fc24facbec8f34fb1017133858842b/node
Welcome to Node.js v14.16.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> dns.lookup('localhost', {hints: dns.ADDRCONFIG|dns.V4MAPPED}, console.log)
GetAddrInfoReqWrap {
  callback: [Function: log],
  family: 0,
  hostname: 'localhost',
  oncomplete: [Function: onlookup]
}
> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:67:26)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:131:14) {
  errno: -3007,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'localhost'
}
```

any idea what the problem could be despite /etc/hosts? It definitly contains localhost.

And yes normal hosts are working:

```
[devcontainer]$ curl google.de
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: Does the container have an /etc/nsswitch.conf file? Does that file tell it to use the 'files' module for host lookup? Does the container in fact have the 'files' module (libnss_files.so.2) in /lib or /usr/lib?

Comment: it seems that someone removed the whole nsswitch file from the container https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/commit/5dbd3b833b40217cb1a63d4f52351ae8876ba86c#diff-4d51d03790cd393fc9ae1cd33a6cf83bcd4b24f1e8d3f52a30812b5b5694ef5a i try to mount a copy in it

Comment: you are my hero, I've been desperate for hours, and now it works again, thank you!

Comment: @user1686 maybe you want to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard hostname lookup functions on Linux use `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to determine where they should look for information. Make sure that file exists and is world-readable.

The nsswitch.conf file specifies which *modules* to use for each database. For example, there is a standard 'files' module that reads /etc/hosts (and /etc/passwd); there is a 'dns' module which makes DNS queries; and it's possible to install modules for LDAP, NIS, MySQL, etc.

Make sure nsswitch.conf contains a `hosts:` line, and that the line mentions the `files` module somewhere in it (modules are processed left-to-right).

For example, typically it will be configured sorta like this (modern distros might include more modules, but that's the basic minimum that everyone has):

```
passwd: files
hosts: files dns
...
```

This configuration tells the "hosts" lookup functions to first use the 'files' module (which reads /etc/hosts), and then if it has no succesful results, then use the 'dns' module (which makes DNS queries according to /etc/resolv.conf).

Each module exists as a library in /lib (or /usr/lib). So if you want to use the `files` module, then make sure that your system actually has `/lib/libnss_files.so.2` installed.

---

Note that if the nsswitch.conf file is missing or unreadable, Glibc uses this hardcoded default configuration:

```
passwd: files
hosts: dns [!UNAVAIL=return] files
...
```

This means that DNS will be tried first, and if it provides *any* answer (even a "not found"), the query will immediately stop there – the "files" module (to read /etc/hosts) won't be called at all.

---

You can test the name service configuration using `getent`:

- To query according to nsswitch.conf:
  `getent hosts localhost`
  `getent passwd root`
- To query a specific module (bypassing nsswitch.conf):
  `getent -s dns hosts example.com`
  `getent -s files hosts localhost`

Comment: Never knew this, thanks again!